# Do I need to know AspectJ and annotations for Spring Roo?

Tags: java, spring-roo

I have read the Spring books and know the basics about AOP. I want to learn Spring Roo but I don't know AspectJ and annotations.

Do I need to learn those to get started with Spring Roo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to, as Roo manages all the AspectJ artifacts for you - the generated .aj files. However, knowing the underlying AspectJ concepts will help with what Spring Roo/Spring in general, is doing under the covers - [Spring Roo Critical Technologies: AspectJ.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/architecture.html#architecture-critical-technologies-aspectj)